# Is there any way to alter line spacing/margins/padding for a UITextView inside a UIStackView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uitextview, uistackview

So I have a prototype cell.

It's a horizontal stack view with several buttons, and a text view as the rightmost subview.

My problem is that the text view's text is too high up, which allows two lines to fit into the cell's height instead of just one. But I need to keep the font size at this value, so I can't increase it and achieve one-line-per-cell that way.

**So I need to somehow make the line spacing/margins/etc. greater for the text view so that when there's only one line of text in it, the text will be centered in the cell.** Or some approximation of that, such as perhaps setting margins around the text view itself.

Yet I can't seem to find a way to do any of this.

I tried setting constraints for the text view, but that just somehow makes the whole stack view vanish. I tried going into the Size Inspector for the text view and setting explicit layout margins, but Xcode altogether crashes from that completely, so I figure that's probably not allowed.

Can anyone knowledgeable about UITextViews please share some insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research and testing, this appears to be the best way to set insets for the text in a text view:

```
cellField.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0)
```

The same thing can be set via Storyboard in the UITextView's Identity Inspector tab by adding a "textContainerInset" runtime attribute with type "Rect" and setting desired values.

Answer (score 0):

Use UITextField and set the height constraint greater than equal to a value at priority 250.

Comment: I can't use UITextField. I need to use a UITextView so that text entered into any given table cell can take up multiple lines. Unless I'm somehow gravely mistaken about UITextField capabilities?